# PM2 cluster mode additional processes use wrong script path

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have a nodejs app running on a server with the following `ecosystem.config.js`:

```
    module.exports = {
      apps : [
    {
        name      : "app.website.com",
        script    : "/var/www/app.website.com/node/server.js",
        cwd       : "/var/www/app.website.com/node/",
        instances : "max",
        exec_mode : "cluster",
        max_memory_restart: "500M",
        out_file  : "/var/log/pm2.app.website.com.out.log",
        error_file: "/var/log/pm2.app.website.com.err.log",
        merge_logs: true,
        pid_file  : "/var/run/pm2.app.website.com.pid"
    },
    {
        name      : "dev1.website.com",
        script    : "/var/www/dev1.website.com/node/server.js",
        cwd       : "/var/www/dev1.website.com/node/",
        instances : 1,
        exec_mode : "cluster",
        max_memory_restart: "500M",
        out_file  : "/var/log/pm2.dev1.website.com.out.log",
        error_file: "/var/log/pm2.dev1.website.com.err.log",
        merge_logs: true,
        pid_file  : "/var/run/pm2.dev1.website.com.pid"
    },
      ]
    }
```

When I start this, I see in pm2 status:

- 3 processes started for `app.website.com`
- 2 of them constantly restarting

in pm2 monit

I see that one of the 3 processes has a script path of

`/var/www/app.website.com/node/server.js`

whereas the 2 others have a script path of

`/var/www/app.website.com/node`

therefore they are erroring.

I can't see why the script paths of the 3 processes would not be the same?

Pm2 version 5.1.1
nodejs version 14.17.6

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've already seen/tried this, but other people with similar issues have fixed them by deleting and recreating the application, or other similar steps ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441633/pm2-script-execution-path-is-incorrect-doesnt-match-the-one-in-ecosystem-confi)).